# PHP - User Management Delete Problem

Tags: php

I am working on a custom content management system. I was instructed to do some changes, and this is what I need to do. I need to create a user management page which allows the administrator to delete (or disable his status) a user from the database.

This is my User Management Page:

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT author_id, author_email as Email, author_name as Name
        FROM authors
        ORDER BY Name
        LIMIT 0, 30';

$result = mysql_query($query);

?>

<table class="listing">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Author ID</td>
        <th>Author E-Mail</th>
        <th>Author Name</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++) {
        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
            echo '<tr class="even">';
        } else {
            echo '<tr class="odd">';
        }
        echo "<td>{$row['author_id']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['Email']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['Name']}</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"del-user.php?term={$row['author_id']}\" onclick=\"javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?')\">X</a></td>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is my del-user.php page:

```
<?php
include('inc/config.php');
$title = 'Delete Individual User';
include('inc/db.php');
include('inc/header.php');

echo '<h2>Delete</h2>';

if (isset($GET['term'])) {
$query = "DELETE FROM authors WHERE author_id = {$GET['term']} LIMIT 1";
mysql_query($query) or die('Failed to delete user');
echo '<p>User Deleted</p>';
echo '<p>Back to <a href="manage-users.php">Manage Users </>.</p>';
} else {
echo '<p>Tried to Delete: "';
echo ($GET['term']);
echo '"</p>';
echo '<p>Nothing to Delete</p>';    
}

include('inc/footer.php');
?>
```

I am new to PHP, but this is not working, the author_id value is not being passed to the other page, and it is being left empty. So I cannot delete anything from the del-users.php page.

I'm guessing that this is the problematic part:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"del-user.php?term={$row['author_id']}\" onclick=\"javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?')\">X</a></td>";
```

Anybody knows why this is happening?

Comment: Would be easy and more manageable to various things with ajax calls

Comment: @Stack 101 - I never used ajax, so I prefer not to complicate things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

You send data like this:

```
del-user.php?term={$row['author_id']}
```

So that means that actualy $_GET['term'] contains the id.

You catch the value like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['author_id'])) {
$query = "DELETE FROM authors WHERE author_id = {$_GET['author_id']} LIMIT 1";
```

And it is not good, since $_GET['term'] contains the id, so you have to fix the lower one to look like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])) 
$query = "DELETE FROM authors WHERE author_id = {mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term'])} LIMIT 1";
```

Also you need to expand the select query, since you are not actualy fetching the author_id from the db:

```
$query = 'SELECT author_email as Email, author_name as Name, author_id
        FROM authors
        ORDER BY Name
        LIMIT 0, 30';
```

Please, escape your variables before you trow them to the database...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Cheers

Comment: Kinda incredible... If you added authorId to the select, and changed the $_GET['author_id'] to $_GET['term'], there is nothing left not to work. :) What message do you get?

Comment: Having said that, my url now has 25 at the end, which is the author id "/del-user.php?term=25"

Comment: The correct version of the delete script has $_GET['term'] instead of $_GET['author_id']. Are you absolutely sure you did it? :)

Comment: I got no error, but I got this: "Delete
Tried to Delete: ""

Nothing to Delete" I get this when there is nothing to get

Comment: didn't you tell me it should be term?

Comment: Yes, it should be like this, but not $GET, it should be $_GET :)

Comment: haha thanks mate :) that '_' wasted lots of my time, and since I'm new to PHP's api I would have never noticed what was wrong

Answer (score 1):

use author_id in your query

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT author_id, author_email as Email, author_name as Name
        FROM authors
        ORDER BY Name
        LIMIT 0, 30';

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

?>

Comment: the loop is not the problem, the problem is this part: <td><a href=\"del-user.php?term={$row['author_id']}\" it is not passing the author_id to the other page correctly

Comment: Why would the loop be the problem? :)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your query!

```
$query = 'SELECT author_email as Email, author_name as Name
    FROM authors
    ORDER BY Name
    LIMIT 0, 30';
```

you are not selecting the `author_id`

Answer (score 1):

You pass your user id in the url like this :

```
echo "<td><a href=\"del-user.php?term={$row['author_id']}\"
```

The you must GET `term`, not `author_id` :

```
$query = "DELETE FROM authors WHERE author_id = {$GET['term']} LIMIT 1";
```

And by the way, you should read about prepared query and sql injection ;)